# Finding the general solution of the 2nd order homogeneous equation: $y''+tanh(\frac{t}{2})y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title suggests, i would like to find the general solution of the 2nd order homogeneous equation: $$y''+\tanh\Big(\frac{t}{2}\Big)y'=0$$

In my class, i learnt that given a second order ODE in the form $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$,
if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are integers, we can use the substitution $y(t)=e^{rt}$. For example, given $y''+4y'+4y=0$, it can be easily solved and the substitution leads to the characteristic equation $r^{2}+4r+4=0$ and thereafter we can write down its homogeneous equation as $$y_{c}=C_{1}e^{at}+C_{2}e^{bt}.$$

If the coefficients of the DE are variables, say, $x^{2}y''+xy'+y=0$, which is a Euler equation, we can proceed with the substitution $y=x^{r}$.

However for my question, i noted that it is neither of the form mentioned and i have thought of using the method of "Variation of Parameters" but i am unable to find 2 fundamental sets of solutions to the DE.

How can i proceed with this question? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Try Reduction of Order.

Comment: Hi @Alex, in this case $\tanh \frac{t}{2}$ is a variable in terms of $t$, how can i use the first method i mentioned?

Comment: @Cleytus Sorry, I read it as $\tanh(1/2)$ for some reason. Disregard my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This is is first order equation in $v = y'$

$$ v' = -\tanh \left(\frac{t}{2}\right) \ v $$

That also happens to be seperable

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dylan. I proceeded with your suggestion by letting $v=y'$. However, i could not obtain the factor of $-\frac{1}{2}$ in your solution. Can you kindly elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem. I have edited my answer.

Comment: No worries. Thanks once again.